# Deploying Jenkins to AWS using cloudformation and secrets manager

Tags: jenkins, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-secrets-manager

My objective is to build Jenkins as a docker image and deploy it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

To build the docker image I am using the [Configuration as Code](https://jenkins.io/projects/jcasc/) plugin and injecting all secrets via environment variables in the Dockerfile.

What I am trying to figure out now is how to automate this deployment using CloudFormation or CodePipeline.

My question is:

- Can I fetch secrets from AWS Secrets Manager using either CloudFormation or CodePipeline and inject them as environment variables in the deployment to Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudformation templates can recover secrets from Secrets Manager.  It is somewhat ugly, but works pretty well.  In general, I use a security.yaml nested stack to generate secrets for me in SM, then recover them in other stacks.

I can't speak too much to EB, but if you are deploying that through CF, then this should help.

Generating a secret in SM (CF security.yaml):

```
Parameters:
  DeploymentEnvironment:
    Type: String
    Description: Deployment environment, e.g. prod, stage, qa, dev, or userdev
    Default: "dev"
...
Resources:
...  
  RegistryDbAdminCreds:
    Type: 'AWS::SecretsManager::Secret'
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "RegistryDbAdminCreds-${DeploymentEnvironment}"
      Description: "RDS master uid/password for artifact registry database."
      GenerateSecretString:
        SecretStringTemplate: '{"username": "artifactadmin"}'
        GenerateStringKey: "password"
        PasswordLength: 30
        ExcludeCharacters: '"@/\+//:*`"'
      Tags:
      -
        Key: AppName
        Value: RegistryDbAdminCreds
```

Using the secret in another yaml:

```
Parameters:
  DeploymentEnvironment:
    Type: String
    Description: Deployment environment, e.g. prod, stage, qa, dev, or userdev
    Default: "dev"
...
Resources:
  DB:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    DependsOn: security
    Properties:
      Engine: postgres
      DBInstanceClass: db.t2.small
      DBName: quilt
      MasterUsername: !Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:RegistryDbAdminCreds-${DeploymentEnvironment}:SecretString:username}}'
      MasterUserPassword: !Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:RegistryDbAdminCreds-${DeploymentEnvironment}:SecretString:password}}'
      StorageType: gp2
      AllocatedStorage: "100"
      PubliclyAccessible: true
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref SubnetGroup
      MultiAZ: true
      VPCSecurityGroups:
      - !GetAtt "network.Outputs.VPCSecurityGroup"
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Join [ '-', [ !Ref StackName, "dbinstance", !Ref DeploymentEnvironment ] ]
```

The trick is in `!Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:RegistryDbAdminCreds-${DeploymentEnvironment}:SecretString:username}}'` and `!Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:RegistryDbAdminCreds-${DeploymentEnvironment}:SecretString:password}}'`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do stuff in this way in general, but couldn't you just use the AWS CLI to get the secrets from Secrets Manager directly from your ELB instance?